# Почему не работают градиенты?

Tags: css

Почему не работают градиенты? Должно быть красным и с узором! [Сам код](https://jsfiddle.net/1tb7mf9s/).

```
.svet {
  height: 470px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 7px solid #777;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background: radial-gradient(hsl(0, 100%, 40%), hsl(0, 100%, 40%)), linear-gradient(45ged, transparent 5px, #555 5px, #555 6px, transparent 6px), -linear-gradient(135ged, transparent 5px, #333 5px, #333 6px, transparent 6px);
  background-size: 200px 200px, 14px 14px, 14px 14px;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

https://jsfiddle.net/1tb7mf9s/3/

```css
.svet {
    height:  470px; width: 150px;
    border: 7px solid #777; border-radius: 80px;
    background-color: #444;
    background: 
        linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #333 5px, #333 6px, transparent 6px),
        linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 5px,  #555 5px, #555 6px, transparent 6px),
        radial-gradient(hsl(0, 100%, 40%), hsl(0, 100%, 40%)); 
  background-size: 14px 14px, 14px 14px, 200px 200px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="svet"></div>
```

1. `-linear-gradient` -> `linear-gradient`
2. `background-color` надо ставить до `background`
3. `ged` -> `deg`
4. Градиенты в обратном порядке. `background-size` - тоже.

Answer (score -1):

```
.svet {
  height: 470px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 7px solid #777;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background: radial-gradient(hsl(0, 100%, 40%), hsl(0, 100%, 40%)), linear-gradient(45ged, transparent 5px, #555 5px, #555 6px, transparent 6px), linear-gradient(135ged, transparent 5px, #333 5px, #333 6px, transparent 6px);
  background-size: 200px 200px, 14px 14px, 14px 14px;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

Comment: Не работает, естественно. Там 4 ошибки, а не 1.